# Unable to release Android Bundle - location request false positive error

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, android-permissions

I am developing on React Native and using `react-native-geolocation-service` library to access foreground location only (App is for office and other location checkin purposes)

I recently faced this issue, last week I was still able to upload and release my aab just fine, but this week I can't anymore although I only changed a few UI based on user's feedback.
So basically permission and logic wise there's no change to my app.

I even compared both app's permission list and both are exactly the same:
[image: Google permission list]

But then I'm getting this error
[image: error]

even though I have specifically declared here that I'm not accessing background location
[image: error2]
[image: error3]

This app `targetSdkVersion` is 28, if that's important, because I heard starting API 28 there are alot of new restrictions on play console.

Have anyone ever encountered this issue?
If this is a problem with the library I'm using could anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it,

I looked into it and found this
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#foreground

so I just added service tag like so

```
<service
    android:name=".ForegroundLocation"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location">
</service>
```

and updated `targetSdkVersion` to 29 and it worked!

Although still not sure which causes it to work lol

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!